# Managed package with chatter FeedItem on env where Chatter is disabled

Tags: managed-package, chatter, chatter-feed-tracking

If the managed package has functionality based on FeedItem and Chatter=enabled. What will happens if target env doesn't have Chatter enabled? what are the practices to handle the code in this way.

Answer (score 3):

You will not be able to install the managed package until you switch on Chatter in the target org, unfortunately you will receive this error why you try to install:

[image]

You could make it a configuration/custom setting and not create the dependency on Chatter in your DE org, i.e. refer to `FeedItem` [dynamically](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dynamic_dml.htm) in your code thus not creating a dependency on having Chatter installed in the target. Using dynamic code would also allow you to handle the failure gracefully at run-time.

```
    Schema.SObjectType targetType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('FeedItem'); 
    if(targetType == null)
    {
        System.debug('Chatter not enabled'); 
    }
    else
    {
        SObject feedItem = targetType.newSObject(); 
        // do stuff with FeedItem
    }
```

Comment: Quick guy! Totally agree with Phil :) Vote up!